# Number of nonnegative distinct integral solutions

Tags: combinatorics

I was thinking about the following problem:

What is the number of non-negative integral solutions (in terms of $a_{ij}$s) of $$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n,d}a_{ij} \leq N$$ where the vectors $v_1, \ldots v_n$ with $v_i = (a_{i1}, \ldots, a_{id})^T$ must all be distinct?

Without the assumption distinct, the number of solutions should be ${N+nd \choose nd}$ and when d=1 some answers are given in the post: [Partitions Into at Least Two Distinct Parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971870/partitions-into-at-least-two-distinct-parts)

But the final solution in terms of n and d, in full generality is not known to me. Can anyone help please?

Comment: When $d=1$ you have [OEIS A000009](https://oeis.org/A000009). You might try to browse references from that page.